# Subscribing to a service variable in another component?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to listen to a change of a variable in a service I've created, but I cannot seem to get it to work, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

This is my component where I'm trying to listen:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.isOpen.open.subscribe(value => {
      console.log('hello');
    })
  }
```

This is another component where I'm sending it from:

```
  onClick(value){
    if (value === 'open') {
      this.isOpen.isOpen(true);
    } else {
      this.isOpen.isOpen(false);
    }
  }
```

This is my service:

```
  public open: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>()

constructor() { }

isOpen(value) {
    if (value === true) {
        this.open.next(true)
    } else {
        this.open.next(false)
    }
}
```

For some reason that won't console log out, I know my onClick function gets to the service because I can log out the value in it, but it doesn't want to get to my other component. Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you recreate your code on stackblitz, so I can look into it?

Answer (score 0):

You should listen to observables and not subjects

In your service

```
// create subject
private open: Subject <boolean> = new Subject<boolean>()
// create an observable from the subject
public open$: Observable <boolean> = this.open.asObservable();
```

In your component

```
private sub: Subscription; 

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.isOpen.open$
        .subscribe(value => {
            console.log('hello');
        });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    // remove subscription from memory  otherwise you'll have memory leaks
    this.sub.unsubscribe()
}
```

The rest can stay the same